# PHP to calculate latest 31 March

Tags: php, date, financial

i want to calculate latest 31-Mar .... suppose date is 1-Jan-2012 i want result as 31-mar-2011 and if is 1-April-2011 then also i want result 31-mar-2011 and if its 1-mar-2011 it should come as 31-mar-2010.....hope i made my self clear ...(with php) ... i al calculating date with this for financial year ... 
`always between 31-mar-lastyear to 1-April-thisyear` 
 ... year should be taken automatically ...
i was trying like this

```
31-mar-date('y') and 31-mar-date('y')-1
```

but its not working as its taking current year every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using the wonderful [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function of php.

```
<?php

$day = 1;
$month = 1;
$year = 2011;

$date = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);

$targetMonth = 3;
$difference = $month - $targetMonth;

if($difference < 0) {
    $difference += 12;
}

$sameDateInMarch = strtotime("- " . $difference . " months", $date);

echo "Entered date: " . date("d M Y", $date) . "<br />";
echo "Last 31 march: " .  date("t M Y", $sameDateInMarch);

// the parameter 't' displays the last day of the month
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function getLast() {
    $currentYear = date('Y');

    // Check if it happened this year, AND it's not in the future.
    $today = new DateTime();
    if (checkdate(3, 31, $currentYear) && $today->getTimestamp() > mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 31, $currentYear)) {
        return $currentYear;
    }

    while (--$currentYear) {
        if (checkdate(3, 31, $currentYear)) {
            return $currentYear;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump(getLast());
```

It should return the year or `false`.

Comment: undefined function getTimestamp() ??

Comment: @Harinder should be fine now :)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR `if (checkdate(3, 31, $currentYear) && (new DateTime())->getTimestamp() > mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 31, $currentYear)) {` this line

Comment: Too bad I don't have PHP at the moment, try removing the ( and ) around `new DateTime()` so that it's like: `new DateTime()->getTimestamp()`. Updated my answer.

Comment: How's that possible? The example on PHP does just that: http://fi.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Answer (score 1):

```
if (date('m')>3) {
    $year = date('Y').'-'.(date('Y')+1);
} else {
    $year = (date('Y')-1).'-'.date('Y');
}
echo $year;
```

this is to get the current financial year for India

Comment: Code only answers are not helpful. Please [edit] the answer and add explanation.